# Are humans and other animals machines?

Tags: terminology, definitions

It has been said that biological organisms are one kind of machine, albeit highly complex ones. But is this really true? To answer this question, one needs a precise definition of "machine". So, is there a definition of machines in some paper or book, that can tell whether humans and other animals are machines?

Comment: What would it tell you, if they are or aren't? It's just a label, and a pretty vague and useless one. Better questions are, do we think minds can be digitised? And can we programme biology to do nanotechnology tasks?

Comment: A definition that would tell you if biological bodies are machines would have to be the *correct one*. Alas, no definition of a concept is ever the only, absolutely correct one. The best you can find are *consensual*, largely agreed upon definitions. Therefore no definition will ever tell you if humans and animals *are* machines, just according to whom they can be classified as such.

Comment: The answer is No. The origin of the word 'machine' is "a contrivance" which simply requires a Contriver. The only way humans could be machines is, ironically, if they were made by God. This kind of pokes a hole in the notion of religion in general.

Comment: @ScottRowe but the meanings of words evolve, sometimes their modern usage is completely different to their original meaning (e.g. "nice").

Comment: "I've been oiled before, but I've never been a machine." - Ron Jakowski in Grand Theft Auto Online

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I do find that so very distressing, although it doesn't seem to bother anyone else. To me, words are the basis for statements, and statements that change over time make basically everything I could say or believe uncertain. Then I remember that everything is made up anyway and feel better.

Comment: @ScottRowe It's a strange thing to be distressed about. If words didn't evolve we would still be grunting noises and waving our hands around like cavemen. Literally every single word in the English language has evolved from some other word at some point.

Comment: @JBentley So, when is it "good enough" and we can just *use* the words instead of constantly fiddling with them? Refrigerators haven't changed a whole lot in my lifetime, nobody uses them to cook, or grow food or something. As a programmer, I see my job as making myself unnecessary. When a program is done correctly, there is no need to repair, add to or alter it. That's always my goal.

Comment: Sufficiently advanced robotics is indistinguishable from biology ;-)

Comment: @ScottRowe It's a fairly universally accepted fact among (non-delusional) programmers that there's no such thing as a non-trivial piece of software that never has any need to be repaired, added to, or altered. What will you do when your allegedly perfect piece of software needs to run in the latest version of the OS but can't because it is no longer compatible? What do you do when something new is invented and there is no word for it?  Or when something, that an existing word describes, changes? Languages evolve because civilization evolves. We don't live in a static bubble.

Comment: "there's no such thing as a non-trivial piece of software" I tell my students that the definition of a trivial program is one that you know does not contain a bug (as a consolation that they have been writing a non-trivial program ;o).  User requirements change (even if only tick-box features that 99.9% of users never use), so software needs to be adaptable/maintainable.

Comment: Meat bags are poop machines.

Comment: on a slightly more edifying note ;o) Alfred Renyi said that a mathematician is a machine for converting coffee into theorems

Comment: @JBentley I have lots of things with software in them that have never been updated. I had a 25 year old car where I'm pretty sure the engine control hardware and software were never updated or even maintained in any way. That was fine with me. It's probably the most used and important 'computer' in my life. Meanwhile, browsers are updated constantly and often have serious security flaws. No thanks! People need to focus on what is really important: functioning, not features. Longevity, not trendiness. Why is there still so much old Cobol around? It never broke.

Comment: Re words: create new words for new things and leave the old words alone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like this question. It's thorny.

Merriam-Webster [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/machine)
machine so: a mechanically, electrically, or electronically operated device for performing a task.

That is, there is an operator (the entity that will perform the task) and there is a purpose (the task). And the machine is a means by which to perform the task. Various other dictionaries all have variants on this. A machine is some kind of mechanism whereby some task is performed or some physical purpose is achieved.

Can a biological organism be reasonably said to satisfy such a definition?

The usual definition of a biological living thing is (tersely) irritability and reproduction.

Here, irritability is a technical term meaning that the organism can respond in some way to changes in its environment. Some way other than simple physical response. If you put water on clay, it gets wet. If you put water on a seed (a seed in the right conditions etc.) the seed will start to grow. Thus, living things respond to changes in their environment by proceeding with their living processes.

Reproduction means, of course, making some kind of not-necessarily-exact copy of themselves. Possibly by splitting in two, or possibly through sexual reproduction, or some other such means.

The organism attempts to achieve the result of making copies of their DNA. (For DNA based living things. Let us set aside the additional thorny question of whether RNA based viruses are living things.)

In the book [The Selfish Gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Selfish_Gene), Dawkins uses the metaphor of genes having the desire to reproduce. He goes to pains to point out that he is not literally saying they have desires, but that genes that produce results that tend to make copies of themselves will tend to become more common.

So, by this metaphor, an organism is a machine by which a collection of genes attempts to achieve the result of making copies of themselves. They don't literally have desires, but treating the situation *as* *though* *they* *do* is a useful method of analyzing the situation. It allows predictions/explanations of things that would otherwise be difficult to predict or explain.

And this metaphor also exposes several other thorny questions. Another term for the the metaphor is "intentionality." That is, if we imagine a thing has intentionality, can we predict its behavior in useful ways? Often yes. In some cases (a tiger wanting to eat us) it seems quite reaonable to suppose the thing really has intentionality. And it guides you in avoiding getting eaten. In others (a storm wants to blow away your roof) it is possibly a bigger stretch to suppose the storm really has intentionality. But it still lets you make your roof more secure.

So, at least as a metaphor, organisms can be said to be machines used by genes (the operators) for the purpose of making copies of themselves (the task).

Comment: +1 I like that you start with a definition and then follow the parts of the definition.

Comment: Good answer. So genes are the [Ghost in the machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_machine).

Comment: When you said Irritability and Reproduction I thought of "the four Fs". But, if genes are also a mechanism, then it's question-begging to have one mechanism directing another: it is just one big mechanism. So is the universe in total, there is no evidence of direction or purpose, just one big perfect storm trying to kill you.

Comment: That is a *very* restrictive definition of machine.  It also has a meaning in computing/maths, e.g. "Finite state machine" which does not refer to a physical entity.  Biological organisms certainly contain cellular machines, such as ribosomes, which is a machine for constructing proteins from instructions given as RNA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_machine

Comment: Off topic, but I have met many non-biological machines that were "irritable". All you sometimes had to do to make them change their actions was to walk by and they would start making all kinds of weird noises and/or actions. The worst are printers. They are all MFPs, and MF never means "multi-function".

Comment: By this definition, 3D printers are close to being biological living things. They react to their environment and they can reproduce their component parts (albeit they can't yet assemble the new copies).

Comment: Also, see [Universal Constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universal_constructor)

Comment: @JBentley The question of *exactly* what is alive is a deeply thorny question. Note that I deliberately "dodged" on RNA based viruses. If 3D printers get a little smarter, we may well see various SF tropes played out.

Comment: That organisms, and humans in particular, perform mechanical functions that fit many definitions of "machine" is pretty clear. **The *real* question is whether humans are *more than machines.*** Answering the question "is the Mona Lisa a piece of canvas?" or "is a dollar a piece of paper?" with "yes" is correct but misses the point.

Comment: @JBentley OT, but: Self-assembling 3D printers is an old fantasy that misses the point that the chips and wires cannot be printed. All the plastic garbage can be printed, if you insist on making it expensive; all the interesting parts need an industrial infrastructure. A truly self-reproducing machine would indeed be a kind of a new life form but I cannot begin to see how one would be possible. Besides, filament is not part of our natural environment (or Mars', or whatever's).

Comment: *"I like this question. It's thorny."* Best opening to an answer I've ever read.

Comment: @computercarguy The machine that Rage Against The Machine is raging against is probably a printer.

Comment: "Irritability" is an interesting definition for life; I like it, it's very expansive. However, "irritability" is itself a chemical response. Where does one draw the line between a simple response and an irritable one? Seems like it would get pretty grey. I suppose that's the trouble with trying to put messy things into neat boxes.

Answer (score 5):

One of the (many and varied) definitions of "Machine" in the Oxford English Dictionary is:

> A structure regarded as functioning as an independent body, without
> mechanical involvement.

Humans and animals are self-evidently machines by that definition, unless you believe that we are controlled by some external entity pulling our strings.

Another is

> 2. A living body, esp. the human body considered in general or individually. Now chiefly figurative from sense 6b   (cf. sense 8b).

referring to

> 6 b. A complex device, consisting of a number of interrelated parts, each having a definite function, together applying, using, or generating mechanical or (later) electrical power to perform a certain kind of work (often specified by a preceding verbal noun).

which seems to answer the question clearly in the affirmative.

8b is the sense of a person acting without volition (c.f. automaton)

A lot of problems in philosophy seem to boil down to differences in the meanings of words - perhaps we need a less ambiguous language?

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure that definition works, since in physics a machine can be something as simple as a lever. https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/backgrounders/simple-machines-levers

Comment: @computercarguy I suspect that the OED has definitions that cover that usage as well (there are at least 10 definitions IIRC).  I didn't give all of the definitions as that wouldn't be "fair use" and it would give a *very* long answer.

Comment: @computercarguy Back in the office and have access again.  " 7. Mechanics. Anything that transmits force or directs its application." which clearly covers things like levers.

Comment: Yes, I figure that most of the definitions of "machine" would work for the human body, since we have several attached levers, as well as many other things that individually or together work as machines, as you've stated. My original comment was just a minor nitpick. Sorry I didn't convey that so well.

Answer (score 3):

This question is fundamentally about the branch of philosophy known as [Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology), which is broadly concerned with questions of categorization (among other related things such as *being*, *becoming*, and *reality*). Definitions and classifications are tricky things that are often too restrictive or too loose to be useful. I'm reminded of the classic story of Diogenes countering Plato's definition of a man as "a featherless biped" by plucking a chicken and exclaiming, "Behold! A man!"

In any case, definitions are where most people think to start, so there is value in starting our discussion there, but then I think we need to move into the more philosophical questions of **"what does it mean to be human?"** (Ontology) and **"why should/shouldn't we consider living things to be machines?" (Ethics).

### Is there a definition in some paper or book...?

#### Dictionary Definitions

The other answers here start with dictionary definitions. Dictionaries are not the best starting point for developing an ontological argument. An important thing to remember about dictionary definitions is that they are largely descriptive, rather than prescriptive: new definitions are constantly being added and older definitions marked as obsolete or rare as they fall out of usage with *the people who speak the language*. The online version of the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com) maintains many of these older definitions for words in the English language. From there you can see that the word "machine" has had, and continues to have, a variety of definitions dating back to the 16th century. Some of these definitions, such as

> I. A structure regarded as functioning as an independent body, without mechanical involvement.
>
> ...
>
> I.2. A living body, esp. the human body considered in general or individually.

obviously would classify human **bodies** as machines because it is right there in the definition. Other more modern definitions, such as

> IV. An apparatus constructed to perform a task or for some other purpose; also in derived senses.
>
> ...
>
> IV.b. A complex device, consisting of a number of interrelated parts, each having a definite function, together applying, using, or generating mechanical or (later) electrical power to perform a certain kind of work (often specified by a preceding verbal noun).

Are less clearly applicable to humans. Other answers have used these definitions in their arguments, but these definitions only describe how the word "machine" has been used. They are not intended to form the basis of an ontological system that classifies some things as machines and other things as not-machines because the usage of the word machine is very broad in the English language.

#### Famous Philosophical Definitions

"Fine," you might say, "so then what about a book by some famous philosopher that defines machine?" Sure, you could do some reading and see if any famous philosophers have discussed machines in their work.

The first discussion of machines that comes to mind are the [simple machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_machine) of Archimedes, which were later expanded by other ancient Greek thinkers to include levers, screws, pulleys, inclined planes, wedges, and the wheel and axle. Then complex machines were simply assemblages of the simple machines (like a block and tackle being made of many pulleys). Modern machine analysis in engineering usually considers [kinematic pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematic_pair) instead. A biomechanical analysis of the human body shows how kinematic pairs such as revolute and spherical joints are present in the human body. Does this mean that the human **body** is a machine? We've found [tiny insects with gears in their joints](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/this-insect-has-the-only-mechanical-gears-ever-found-in-nature-6480908/) as well! Does that mean these insects are complex machines?

The second and far more recent definition of machine that comes to mind for me is a [Turing Machine](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-machine/), which has been a foundational concept in mathematics and modern computer science. However, the purpose of the Turing Machine concept as it was defined by Turing was to answer theoretical mathematical questions regarding the solvability of certain classes of mathematical problems given a very specific process for executing the computations. Someone more familiar with the mathematics than me might be able to build an argument for why human **thought** could be modeled by a Turing Machine. However, I'm not sure this is the definition you are looking for either.

There are a wide variety of famous philosophers who could each have their own definition of a machine. Perhaps other users on this site can find more relevant philosophical definitions than the examples I give here. However, much like dictionary definitions, they are dependent on context. A lever is a machine according to Archimedes, but is it a Turing Machine? Which definition is the "right" or "true" one? If starting from the definition, whether dictionary or otherwise, of machines is not a good way forward, what is?

### Ontology and Human Being

One question that has interested philosophers for a very long time, if not all of human history, is the nature of what it means to be human. What are the distinctive features of a human? What separates humans from other living things? What separates living things from non-living things? I think this is the true crux of your question: what really separates a non-living thing from a living thing (biological organism in your question).

This question is so broad that it is practically impossible to cover all the possible viewpoints of philosophers over human history in a single answer on this site. Some assert that humans have souls and bodies. Others would say instead that humans have [minds and bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Mind%E2%80%93Body_Dualism). Some would say that there is [nothing to existence except for material things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism), so there is no immaterial soul or mind outside of or separate from the body.

Are human beings just complex machines (bodies) being operated by a soul or mind behind the figurative steering wheel? If the human body is a machine, is that sufficient evidence to say that a human is a machine? If a human mind can be simulated by a Turing Machine does that make a human a machine? The answers really depend on the school of thought that you subscribe to. You can feel free to go down the rabbit hole with some the links I've shared to learn about the many philosophical schools that tackle questions about mind, body, soul, and what it means to be human.

#### When Ontology Becomes Ethics

It would be remiss of me to finish a philosophical discussion without asking "WHY?" To what end do we classify humans and other living things as machines? Why is important that we do not classify humans and other living things as machines?

I will say that one crucial aspect about my intuitive understanding of the concept "machine" is that machines are objects, not subjects. Objects are usually not considered as having moral agency or being worthy of moral consideration. They can be owned, bought, sold, divided, destroyed, modified, and otherwise acted upon without requiring consent or consultation.

Immanuel Kant was one philosopher who was pretty clear about the necessity of [treating humans as ends in themselves, and not a means to an end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant#Ethics). Human beings have been, and continue to be, objectified through institutions including slavery, colonialism, patriarchy, and capitalism. (Side note: this is not to say that Kant was against all of these things.) Humans have always treated other living things as a means to an end: treating plants and animals as food, fuel, clothing, building materials, and/or obstacles to economic development, resulting in massive ecological devastation and species extinction around the globe.

So I will leave you with that thought: what does it mean for our worldview when we start to classify living things as machines?

Comment: Perhaps it means that we are not sufficiently respectful of life? We don't know of any other place in a vast universe where it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like in order to be useful, we can't just define a "**machine**", we have to also define what is "**not a machine**". By some definitions it seems everything could be called a machine. The entire universe may be a machine.

But I think the crux of the question boils down to: *machines are things that can be mapped out and understood with present science and technology*.

Coffee maker? Machine. We fully understand it. We can mass produce them. Jet airplane? A lot more complex but definitely still a machine. Trees? Now we're getting into the interesting parts of the argument because it could be argued that trees are composed of parts, each serving specific functions, and therefore a tree is a machine, following the laws of nature/physics (and thus towards the path of "everything is a machine if you get right down to it").

So I propose two counter-arguments:

**We can't call it a machine if we, as a society, are incapable of understanding how it works.** Maybe humans are machines but we can't declare that when we don't fully understand how they work. Reference modern efforts at artificial intelligence. It's still a long way from producing anything that actually can act and operate as a human. We don't understand the process well enough. So maybe humans actually are machines but we can't really say that because the truth is we don't know all the details.

**Machines must be deterministic.** When you're asking if humans are machines or not, I think the implied question is that machines are deterministic: the axles, cogs and parts determine how the machine will run. If humans are machines, then we must be deterministic: bound by the laws of nature and physics; free will does not exist.

But I think there is actual evidence contrary to this, namely that quantum mechanics is non-deterministic. It may be impossible to fully understand or simulate a human brain due to this non-deterministic nature at the most fundamental level. In that event, we cannot be considered to be machines. (You could take this argument to extremes too, and say that since the universe is built on non-deterministic quantum mechanics, even machines aren't truly machines -- on a macro level they can appear to be but if you fine-tooth the detail far enough, all the way down to the quantum level, then they are no longer entirely deterministic.)

Comment: so an aeroplane is a machine, but a flying saucer created by an extra-terrestrial probably isn't?  "Machines must be deterministic." so a quantum computer is not a machine?

Comment: I think this answer needs to be backed up with a citation to demonstrate that "understanding how it works" is a component of a commonly accepted definition of the word machine. Without that, this answer is based on a flawed (and possibly self-invented) premise.

Comment: I also think you've essentially disproved your argument by contradiction by establishing that machines are not machines under your definition. So clearly this answer can't be on the right path.

Comment: @JBentley - You have to ask "what does someone mean when they ask if humans are machines". Clearly they aren't asking if we are made up of cogs and electronics. Without reading their mind (or a better original question), we're left to guess, but I think the context is always "do we have free will / are we deterministic / are we just robots made of meat". And maybe the broader answer actually is "when you get right down to it, nothing at all in this universe is deterministic" but that may be less philosophy and more physics.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial - Maybe it turns out that the aliens are extremely good at bio-engineering. The flying saucer is literally alive, and mostly or entirely biological in nature. What we thought was a really durable metal exterior is actually a self-regenerating epidermis. Is the flying saucer still a machine? Or is it a space-whale? If we don't understand it, we would only be guessing. (I'm also not sure if a quantum computer is a machine. But then, I'm not an expert on quantum computers.)

Comment: "we're left to guess" - yes, we might be left to guess which definition of "machine" the OP had in mind, but that doesn't mean that we can just invent our own meaning. If we want to reach a sensible conclusion we should start from *some* commonly accepted definition. I've not personally come across a definition which includes an element of "human understanding", hence why I asked for a citation.

Comment: @JBentley - Which I did. You seem to want proof that my definition is "commonly accepted". I would counter by saying the most common definition I can find (e.g. on Wikipedia) does not make for a very interesting question. Are we "a physical system using power to apply forces and control movement to perform an action"? Yes. NEXT.

Comment: @JamieB sorry, I don't see the point in evasion of a counter argument.  Whether something is a machine does not depend on whether we understand it or not.  There is no reason why a machine should be deterministic.  You haven't supplied any justification for your definitions, just stated your axioms, and as I point out there are counter-examples.

Comment: "If we don't understand it, we would only be guessing" if I give a child some piece of complex machinery (say a watch) they won't understand it.  Does that mean it is no longer a machine?  No, of course not.

Comment: BTW, a definition of machine in the OED is " e. A conceptual, abstract, or theoretical mechanism or device; spec. a model or a mathematical abstraction of an existing or hypothetical computer. Cf. Turing machine n.".  An example of this would be a finite state machine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine which includes non-derministic finite state machines.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial - The spaceship example was better. You have no idea if it's biological, a machine, or just a hollowed out piece of metal being moved by some external means you can't see. You're pointing at it and saying "That's a machine!" I'm pointing at it and saying we have no idea if it's a machine and therefore can't call it one until it is fully understood. Whether it's a machine or not is a point of fact -- one we don't currently know and therefore can't claim. More to the point, we don't fully understand the human brain. Is it a machine? We don't know.

Comment: @JamieB.  that is evasion by cherry picking a special case to avoid the counter example.  So why is an aeroplane a machine, but not a non-biological alien spacecraft

Comment: @DikranMarsupial You're getting bogged down in "what is a machine" instead of "what do people mean when they ask if humans and animals are machines". They aren't asking if we fit the wikipedia definition of machine. They are asking about free will and determinism. Otherwise, this question would be on English Learners, not Philosophy.

Comment: "what is a machine" the question is "Are humans and other animals machines?", that question can't be answered unless you can agree what a machine is.  Your own answer is defining what a machine is (in terms of understanding and determinism).  "They are asking about free will and determinism." neither of those things appear in the question.  (and the "a machine must be understandable" has nothing to do with that anyway).

Comment: You're conflating two separate issues: whether something IS a machine (which does not require a human being to understand it) and whether we KNOW it is a machine (which does require a human to understand it). If yesterday we had no idea whether your hypothetical spaceship is a machine (because we didn't understand it), and today we learn enough about it to know it is a machine (because we now do understand it), did it suddenly turn from not-machine to machine overnight? Clearly not - it was always a machine whether we knew it or not.

Comment: "*I would counter by saying the most common definition I can find (e.g. on Wikipedia) does not make for a very interesting question.*" Just because a common definition may lead to an uninteresting question doesn't mean we can just arbitrarily invent any definition we like and use that to reach a sensible conclusion, notwithstanding that that conclusion might be more "interesting". Once we go down that path, we can conclude anything at all by simply tweaking the axioms to our liking.

Comment: "does not make for a very interesting question." a lot of philosophical questions boil down to the ambiguities of natural language.

Comment: I think that philosophical questions boil down to people not being smart enough to understand the issues so as to make the answer bone obvious.

Comment: @ScottRowe - Kinda my thinking here. The OP is clearly not asking if humans and animals are electro-mechanical robots so all this nattering about possible dictionary definitions is silly. Again, if that were the case, we need to direct OP to English Learners because that's the proper forum to discuss word usage and dictionary definitions. In the context of a philosophical forum, it seems reasonable to assume OP was asking about some philosophical angle, e.g. determinism.

Answer (score 1):

I think here suits terminology from a computer science. State machine is a device which switches between internal states in repetitive ways (cycles).

In this perspective, humans are machines. One of many our cycles : Sleep - Eat breakfast - Go to Work - Work - Go Home - Eat - Watch Tv - Go to sleep. Next day - all over again, maybe with slight modifications.

Or machinery at the microscopic level in our cells : Burn calories - Divide - Emit toxins into the fluids. And same again, until cell death. So bigger machinery can be constructed from a smaller machinery sets.

I don't think that there can exist such a unique creature which could switch  internal states only in a unique and non-repeatable pattern. Even "broken" machines (mentally ill people for example) has inner triggers of acting one way or another.

For acting in a complete unique way, you must have some "device" in your brains which evaluates uniqueness of each and every action, which, alas, by definition is yet another machinery. Because such introspection would have clear rules set of how to filter out  this or that non-unique action.

So, no way out. Once machine has been created, - it will stay so until the end. Like it or not.

Comment: "Siphonaptera" is a name used to refer to the following rhyme by Augustus De Morgan: "*Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em, And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum. And the great fleas themselves, in turn, have greater fleas to go on; While these again have greater still, and greater still, and so on.*" From De Morgan's A Budget of Paradoxes... the possibility that all particles may be made up of clusters of smaller particles, 'and so down, for ever'; and similarly that planets and stars may be particles of some larger universe, 'and so up, for ever'

Comment: This is called a fractal pattern. Indeed, one possibility from many is that we will never get-out of structural components list in the universe, if the universe has fractal-like pattern.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that the other answers are carefully avoiding the elephant in the room: The profound feeling that there is more to us (and to a lesser degree, perhaps, to other organisms as well) than our material appearance.

Religions are the most obvious expressions of this: They claim that humans are linked to a transcendental divine being that imbues them with something special that eludes scientific approaches, a soul, if you want.

Even if one doesn't buy into spirituality in one of its many flavors, humans undeniably are quite special among the machines. The following list of distinctions applies, to a lesser degree, to (some) animals as well.

- Humans are self-conscious and self-modifying.
- Humans are not operated, but instead they are operators.
- We don't serve a purpose (which, as an aside, is opposing the typical religious tenets) but we use other things for purposes of our own.
- In a way, we are meta-machines: We design and build other machines.

Comment: "Humans are not operated, but instead they are operators." what evidence do you have for this?  How do you know you are not a non-player character in a simulation and merely programmed to think that you are an operator?

Comment: @Dikran I think, therefore I am; I plan, and thus I act.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't just the story your conscious mind has been fed by your subconscious or the effects of your programming in the simulation?  Cogito ergo sum suggests something exists, but it doesn't settle what it establishes to exist.  Computers can plan and act.  Whether there is some non-material part of us is likely to remain a matter of faith/belief.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Well, actually almost everything is a matter of "belief", apart from that core statement of existence, if we play hardball (e.g., our *material* existence even more than our immaterial one, which is proven by the thought). Btw, note that I didn't want to advocate the existence of some "soul"; I just noted that we, as mechanisms go, are quite extraordinary.

Comment: Indeed, we can have no certain knowledge of anything that isn't a tautology, just varying degrees of (hopefully justified) belief.  We are extraordinary, sadly not uniformly in a good way ;o)